# How to use border-radius while converting html to pdf using xhtmltopdf

Tags: python, html, django-templates, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to round the corners of my table, border-radius doen't seem to work when I convert the below HTML to PDF using xhtmltopdf pdf generator. Below is the HTML written for content file name is sticker_print.html :

```
<div class="sticker" style="height:196px">
            <table class="sticker_box" align="left">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #222;background-color: #ffffff;">
                        <h3 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;">Batch Sticker</h3>
                        <h5 style="padding: 0 0 0 10px;">Batch ID</h5>
                        <p>MFG Date</p>
                        <p style="padding-bottom:0px;"><img src="http://www.computalabel.com/Images/C128ff@2x.png" width="195px" height="26px"><span> Bar Code </span></p>
                        <p style="text-align: left; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                            <img src="https://www.kaspersky.com/content/en-global/images/repository/isc/2020/9910/a-guide-to-qr-codes-and-how-to-scan-qr-codes-2.png" width="65px" height="65px">
                            <span style="display: block;margin-top: 0px;">QR Code</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

PDF CODE

```
pdf = render_to_pdf('sticker_print.html')
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm not using the same PDF engine as you (and your question is 6 months old), I solved this issue by using `corner-radius` instead of `border-radius` on a table cell or div.

Comment: What library you use?